# How to read video stream as input in OpenCV python?

Tags: python, opencv

i have a nikon d90 camera. I want to get realtime video to my pc. And i want to read that streaming video using OpenCV python for processing the video frames.how to do that?.pls help me.

Comment: Please provide more info.

Comment: Operating system, used code in OpenCv, Python version.  Are you able to see the camera as device in a player e.g. VLC ?

Comment: I can't fully understand what you need to do!!! Please clarify your question

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comments above, more details are needed to know exactly how you are planning connect your camera. Here's a working example for a webcam, notice that you should replace the `input_id` with your camera's. You would work on `frame` for further processing.

```
import cv2

def get_video(input_id):
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(input_id)
    while True:
        okay, frame = camera.read()
        if not okay:
            break

        cv2.imshow('video', frame)
        cv2.waitKey(1)
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_video(0)
```

Comment: first of all thanks for response. i have a usb cable to connect that camera to pc which has windows 7 operating system. Also there is camera control pro software in my computer .i can watch the live video using that software. And i want to process the real time video from that camera. How to do that in openCV. i am a beginer in this and havent started coding. Dont know how to read the data first. pl help me

Comment: You need the camera port number and change it in `get_video(0)` to the correct number. That is how you can "read" the video in OpenCV.

Comment: and also i want to say that   in the above code that Pedro gave no?..there is  cv2.VideoCapture(input_id) right?..But this for webcam streaming right? i want the same but for the nikon camera which is connected by usb to my pc

Comment: how to get the port number?